# VPN protected resource and accessible via authenicated API - design

Tags: vpn

let's imagine a simple system deployed on GCP. There is public, authenticated (token, IP whitelisting) API exposed by our system. There is a protected resource R (SQL database) that is accessible by API. We would like to add to our system additional possibility accessing via VPN for some our clients, it means that part of R should be accessible only via VPN and, other part of R should accessible still via public API. Can you hint me how to correctly design it?

Comment: What's GCP? Please add details (diagram, device types, configs) of your current setup. Or is this a general question?

Comment: It is general question

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host/server/VM configurations are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you put a public server in a demilitarized zone (DMZ).

Optimally, you configure public services and private services to different interfaces/IP addresses. Alternatively, you can use different TCP ports (e.g. port 443 to public HTTPS access and port 8443 for private/administrative HTTP access).

On the public-facing firewall, you permit traffic to the public IP/port (possibly using port forwarding/destination NAT, depending on design). On the firewall facing the private network, you can permit traffic to more services.

Then you can add a VPN gateway, allowing VPN peers access to more than the public services.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
> Then you can add a VPN gateway, allowing VPN peers access to more than the public services.
How to do it?

Comment: What are your premises? We can't detail the selection, design and configuration of a VPN solution within the scope of this site.